# For loop query sql database in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, for-loop, while-loop

I am not too sure how to use a for loop or a while loop which ever suits my problem better.
I need to query database based on selected item in drop down list and the field Processed ='False'

then my code within the loop

then update database based on selected item in drop down list and the field Processed becomes ='True'

my code is as below, I need the the loop to be within document.open and document.close

```
    protected void GenerateReport(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataRow dr = GetData("SELECT * FROM OnSiteWorkTx where DocID = " + DropDownListPdf.SelectedItem.Value).Rows[0]; ;
        Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 88f, 88f, 10f, 10f);
        Font NormalFont = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 12, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK);

        using (System.IO.MemoryStream memoryStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
        {
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, memoryStream);
            Phrase phrase = null;
            PdfPCell cell = null;
            PdfPTable table = null;
            BaseColor color = null;

            document.Open();

            //Header Table
            table = new PdfPTable(2);
            table.TotalWidth = 500f;
            table.LockedWidth = true;
            table.SetWidths(new float[] { 0.6f, 0.3f });


            cell = ImageCell("~/pic.jpg", 40f, PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT);
            table.AddCell(cell);



            phrase = new Phrase(new Chunk("QAF 018/2\n", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK)));
            phrase.Add(new Chunk("On Site Work                        " + "Visit " + dr["VisitNumber"] + "   " + dr["PageNumber"], FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 15, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK)));
            // table.AddCell(PhraseCell(new Phrase("On Site Work", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 20, Font.UNDERLINE, BaseColor.BLACK)), PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
            table.AddCell(PhraseCell(phrase, PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
            cell = PhraseCell(new Phrase(), PdfPCell.ALIGN_RIGHT);
            cell.Colspan = 2;
            cell.PaddingBottom = 13f;
            table.AddCell(cell);



            //Separater Line
            color = new BaseColor(System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#A9A9A9"));
            DrawLine(writer, 25f, document.Top - 79f, document.PageSize.Width - 25f, document.Top - 79f, color);
            DrawLine(writer, 25f, document.Top - 80f, document.PageSize.Width - 25f, document.Top - 80f, color);
            document.Add(table);


            table = new PdfPTable(2);
            table.SetWidths(new float[] { 2f, 10f });
            table.TotalWidth = 480f;
            table.LockedWidth = true;
            table.SpacingBefore = 15f;
            table.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT;



            table.AddCell(PhraseCell(new Phrase("Company: ", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 10, BaseColor.BLACK)), PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
            phrase = new Phrase(new Chunk(dr["Company"] + "          " + "           " + "          " + "           " + "           " + "           " + "           " + "Email: " + dr["Email"], FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 10, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK)));
            table.AddCell(PhraseCell(phrase, PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
            cell = PhraseCell(new Phrase(), PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER);
            cell.Colspan = 7;
            cell.PaddingBottom = 10f;
            table.AddCell(cell);

            table.AddCell(PhraseCell(new Phrase("Plant: ", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 10, BaseColor.BLACK)), PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
            phrase = new Phrase(new Chunk(dr["Plant"] + "          " + "           " + "          " + "           " + "           " + "           " + "          " + "Contact Tel: " + dr["ContactTel"], FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 10, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK)));
            table.AddCell(PhraseCell(phrase, PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
            cell = PhraseCell(new Phrase(), PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER);
            cell.Colspan = 2;
            cell.PaddingBottom = 10f;
            table.AddCell(cell);

            table.AddCell(PhraseCell(new Phrase("Contact Person: ", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 10, BaseColor.BLACK)), PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
            phrase = new Phrase(new Chunk(dr["ContactPerson"] + "          " + "           " + "          " + "           " + "           " + "           " + "Fax No: " + dr["FaxNo"], FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 10, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK)));
            table.AddCell(PhraseCell(phrase, PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
            cell = PhraseCell(new Phrase(), PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER);
            cell.Colspan = 2;
            cell.PaddingBottom = 10f;
            table.AddCell(cell);
            document.Add(table);
            document.NewPage();

            try
       {    string constring = "Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=FAUMA;User ID=sa;Password=P@ssw0rd";
            string Query = "update OnSiteWorkTx set Processed = 'True' where Company = '" + DropDownListPdf.Text + "'and Processed = 'False'";
            SqlConnection conDatabase = new SqlConnection(constring);
            SqlCommand cmdDatabase = new SqlCommand(Query, conDatabase);
            SqlDataReader reader;
            conDatabase.Open();
            reader = cmdDatabase.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {

            conDatabase.Close();

        }
            document.Close();

            byte[] bytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
            memoryStream.Close();
            Response.Clear();


                //Save as Attachment

                Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=OnSiteWork.pdf");
                Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
                Response.Buffer = true;
                Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
                Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
                Response.End();
                Response.Close();
            }
        }


    }
```

Comment: Please leave only the relevant code for your question. Do you need to know how to update a set of record in the database table OnSiteWorkTx?

Comment: Alhtough it does not answer your question, please read about SQL injection attacks, bind parameters and `using` blocks. It will improve your code a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To update the company selected in your dropdownlist, you need something like this.

```
try
{    
     string constring = "Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=FAUMA;User ID=sa;Password=P@ssw0rd";
     string Query = @"update OnSiteWorkTx set Processed = 1 
                      where Company = @company and Processed = 0";
     using(SqlConnection conDatabase = new SqlConnection(constring))
     using(SqlCommand cmdDatabase = new SqlCommand(Query, conDatabase))
     {
         cmdDatabase.Parameters.AddWithValue("@company", DropDownListPdf.Text);
         conDatabase.Open();
         cmdDatabase.ExecuteNonQuery();
     }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Response.Write(ex.Message);
}
```

You prepare your command using a parameterized query instead of a string concatenation and use just one ExecuteNonQuery to update all the relevant records for the company. Notice also that passing the strings 'True' or 'False' as values for a bit field in SQLServer doesn't work. You pass 1 for True and 0 for False.

Concerning the execution of this code for every row returned by the GetData method, you coud simply refactor your code in this way

```
protected void GenerateReport(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = GetData("SELECT * FROM OnSiteWorkTx where DocID = " +
                            DropDownListPdf.SelectedItem.Value);
    foreach(DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        PrepareDocument(dr);
    }
}
```

where PrepareDocument is all the code that you have already written and that works on a single row

```
private void PrepareDocument(DataRow dr)
{
    Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 88f, 88f, 10f, 10f);
    Font NormalFont = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 12, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK);

    using (System.IO.MemoryStream memoryStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
    {
         ...... all the code above, but with the DataRow passed from the calling method
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for that, and about looping the code before i update

Comment: Steve, thank you again,i had not noticed the edit for prepare document, i came back to look at the update code. I appreciate it #ImSoHappy for it now works.